# How to force SVG icon to scale?

Tags: html, svg

Below is a simple example of an SVG icon being displayed in a blue DIV. First, the CSS:

```
div.box {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: blue;
}

svg.icon {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    color: white;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

... and now the HTML:

```
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <g id="box-icon"><path d="M21 19V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2zM8.5 13.5l2.5 3.01L14.5 12l4.5 6H5l3.5-4.5z"></path></g>
        </defs>
    </svg>


    <div class="box">
        <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 72 72"><use xlink:href="#box-icon"></use></svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/b9fxvu7k/

Note that the DIV, the icon, and icon's viewbox are all sized to 72 pixels. But the browser insists on rendering the icon as 24 pixels no matter what size I specify for the DIV, icon, and viewbox. I need the SVG icon to scale up to the size of its container. Does anyone see what is missing? Or, is the SVG path I specified hardcoded to 24x24?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a scale factor to your `g` using the `transform` attribute, like this:

```
<g transform="scale(3)" ...
```

You can also achieve the same result in CSS:

```
#button-icon {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

But the CSS method apparently doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Thanks, Hassan! I found the CSS solution also required "transform-origin: 0 0" to keep the icon from moving outside of the blue box. And as you stated, it doesn't work at all on IE. But the transform attribute on the "g" element  worked perfectly, even on IE (at least IE 11).